# C# string should not contain only white spaces or any special character except ,.';:"

Tags: c#, .net, regex, model-validation

I need a regular expression pattern to verify string does not contain only white spaces(blank with multiple space only)(Ex: "    ".length = 4) and should not contain !@$#%^&*() characters.

Regex regex = new Regex(@".*\S+.*");
This one checks for white spaces. I need both condition in one Regex pattern.

```
   Result
   ---------
```

- "    " : false
- "ad af" : true
- " asd asd " : true
- "  asdf  " : true
- "asdf@df dsfs " : false
- "  # " : false

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: Kindly refer to this answer: [How do I not allow special characters, but allow space in regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106109/how-do-i-not-allow-special-characters-but-allow-space-in-regex)

Comment: [RegularExpression(@"^[^~!@#$%&*]+$", ErrorMessage = "Given value is not correct")] . This checks for special characters but i need to check for spaces (textbox contains only spaces).

Comment: Both condition in one regular expression

Answer (score 2):

As a single regex:

```
!Regex.IsMatch(input, "^\s+$|[!@$#%^&*()]");
```

This means:

```
^\s+$        //Is entirely composed of one or more whitespace characters 
|            //OR
[!@$#%^&*()] //Contains any one of the given special characters
```

This regex returns the opposite of the truth you want (i.e. it looks for anything that is all whitespace OR does contain a special char), so we NOT it with `!` to match your requirements

Comment: I required in RegularExpression[RegexPattern] annotation in .net MVC model. So I need a pattern that does return false if condition not satisfies. Its not possible to give NOT with !.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a regex for "only alphabets with space in between" you can use this:

```
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]+
```

If you want allow, numbers also,
use this:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9 ]+
```