# Combine two regular expression into one while validating Attribute

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, model-validation

I have two regular expression.

1. `[RegularExpression(@".*[^ ].*", ErrorMessage ="Something")]`
   validate string that only contains spaces(Not any other characters 
   Ex: `"       ".length = 7`).
2. `[RegularExpression(@"^[^~!@#$%&*]+$", ErrorMessage = "something")]`
   validate string that contains `~!@#$%&*` special characters.

How can I combine both regex into one, because Duplicate Regular expression annotation is not allowed in asp.net mvc.

Comment: @".*[^ ].*" :  for space validation, I am using

Comment: What's stopping you adding a space to the second expression? You want `~!@#$%& ` to all be invalid, right?

Comment: I did n't get you. second option?

Comment: Then it will not allow space in my string. I need space but not string with only space. Like : "       " : false    "   asdfa    asdf   " : true

Comment: Something like `@"^(?=.*[^ ])[^~!@#$%&*]+$"` should work I guess.

Comment: Can you add that to your question, because it's not clear that's what you want.

Comment: Ok. I will add it to question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54773228/c-sharp-string-should-not-contain-only-white-spaces-or-any-special-character-exc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# string should not contain only white spaces or any special character except ,.';:"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54773228/c-sharp-string-should-not-contain-only-white-spaces-or-any-special-character-exc)

Comment: @Sipun Next time, please [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54780873/edit) your question if you want to add some details.

Comment: Ya, Its working. Thank you so much Jerry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^[^~!@#$%&*]*[^~!@#$%&*\s][^~!@#$%&*]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0AzAdp/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^~!@#$%&*]*` - 0+ chars other than a char in the `~!@#$%&*` list
- `[^~!@#$%&*\s]` - a char other than a char in the `~!@#$%&*` list and whitespace
- `[^~!@#$%&*]*` - 0+ chars other than a char in the `~!@#$%&*` list
- `$` - end of string.

NOTE: To also allow an empty string you need to wrap the pattern between the anchors within an optional group: `^(?:[^~!@#$%&*]*[^~!@#$%&*\s][^~!@#$%&*]*)?$`.